# How to access the correct cell width inside a UITabelViewCell Class?

Tags: swift, uitableview, layout, constraints

I am trying to obtain the correct width for a custom cell inside a UITableViewCell Class. I tried the below:

```
    import UIKit

    import ChameleonFramework

    class IsectionsCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        let cellContainer: UIView = {

            let container = UIView()

            container.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatPink()

            container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            return container

        }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

            addSubview(cellContainer)

    }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

        }

    func applyAppropriateSizeAndConstraintsForCellItems() {

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

                cellContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),

                cellContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -1*((self.frame.size.width)/2)),

                cellContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),

                cellContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor)

])
    }

    }
```

However, as it can be seen from the attached image, the below line of code used above did not return the correct width as the total width was not split equally in half:

```
-1*((self.frame.size.width)/2)
```

Any idea what did I do wrong here, how can I obtain the true width of the custom Cell, which in my mind should be equal to the width of the Table it is going to be placed inside?

Regards,
Shadi Hammoudeh.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do base the constraint on the frame. Use the proper constraint.

Change:

```
cellContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -1*((self.frame.size.width)/2))
```

to:

```
cellContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellContainer.superview.centerXAnchor)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this sorted out my problem, much appreciated :)